# Replacing one special character with another in a database table field value using PHP MySql

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a quite large table and wanted to update all - with _ in one particular field values.

Eg: Field name is keyword

> The current value is "supercomputing-asia-conference" and the expected
>   result would be supercomputing_asia_conference

I don't need to retrieve the data, I just wanted to update the value when executing the SQL query. I'm trying to write an SQL query to do this, can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all fields in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145076/replace-all-fields-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_Table set keyword = REPLACE(keyword, "-", "_");
```